# Linear relationships for two (x,y) graphs

Tags: math, graph, coordinates, relationship

I have `x,y` data coming in from a `[coordinates1]` database (GIS - but this could be any database). I have my application with it's own coordinate system, referencing THE SAME MAP.

I have established that a linear relationship exists between coordinates1 (x,y) and `coordinates2(x,y)` as I have subtracted two different coordinates1 and `coordinates2` (dividing `x1` with `x2` and `y1` with `y2`) and in all cases I get them both showing 0.724 or 0.141 or 0.825 respectively i.e. coordinates1 + coordinates2.

What I now need to figure out - or you help - is that if `coordinates1(100000,200000)` and `coordinates2(0.125,0.255)` how do I calculate `coordinates2(x,y)` from the data in `coordinates1(x,y)`?

Comment: You can't: (100000,200000) and (0.125,0.255) are linearly independent.

Comment: ok... so you have (x1,y1) and (x1',y1') and want to compute (x2',y2') from (x2,y2), right?

Comment: (100000,200000) and (0.125,0.255) are just examples, as I didn't want to enter the coordinates as the live data is licenced. Does this still mean that the co-ordinates are linearly independent?

Comment: Yes Erich Mirabal you are correct

Comment: do the two coordinate systems have the same origin (0,0) locations?

Comment: @balpha i'm not sure what you mean, even if we were talking about vectors, those wouldn't be linearly independent.  if they were (100000,200000) and (0.125,0.25), then they would be linearly independent vectors

Comment: @Erich it removes a degree of freedomon, making the math easier...

Comment: @Kip: No, if they were v1 = (100000,200000) and v2 = (0.125,0.25) they would be linearly dependent, becaus v1 = 800000 * v2.

Comment: Oh, and I assume we're talking about vectors, because what the OP describes in his second paragraph looks like a check for linear dependence.

Comment: @Vault: can you please make your problem more precise? Rewrite the content into more a more rigorous notation? (x,y) for DB's coordinates and (x',y') for your app's coordinates? (i.e. (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x1',y1'), (x2',y2'), etc...). It seems everyone is still not sure how you are drawing the fact that your data has a linear relationship.

Comment: From the GIS database I have a point at the bottom of the map (538129.75, 169167.5) which has an identical location in my map with co-ordinates (-4.166675, 53816227). I then choose another location (top of the map) (537353.5, 179877)
Subtract first =
537353.5 - 538129.75 = -776.25
179877 - 169167.5 = 10709.5
Subtract second=
4.215052 - 4.166675 = 0.048377               
54.484276 - 53.816227 = 0.668049   

If I then divide I get
776.25/10709.5 = 0.0724823
0.048377/0.668049 = 0.0724153  

this prooves the linear relationship (it is a bit off because numbers in map are guesstimates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I'm going to call coordinates in your base (*x<sub>n</sub>*, *y<sub>n</sub>*), and coordinates in your target (*u<sub>n</sub>*, *v<sub>n</sub>*).

Now, if we assume:

1. The origins of the two coordinate systems are the same.
2. The orientation of the two coordinate systems are the same (i.e. one is not rotated with respect to the other).

In this case you only need one set of points {(*x<sub>1</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>*), (*u<sub>1</sub>*, *v<sub>1</sub>*)} to determine the location of (*u<sub>n</sub>*, *v<sub>n</sub>*):

- *u<sub>n</sub>* = *u<sub>1</sub>*/*x<sub>1</sub>* * *x<sub>n</sub>*
- *v<sub>n</sub>* = *v<sub>1</sub>*/*y<sub>1</sub>* * *y<sub>n</sub>*

Note: we must have *x<sub>1</sub>* ≠ 0, *y<sub>1</sub>* ≠ 0

---

On the other hand, if the two coordinate systems have different origins (but they are still not rotated with respect to one another), we will need two sets of points {(*x<sub>1</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>*), (*u<sub>1</sub>*, *v<sub>1</sub>*)} and {(*x<sub>2</sub>*, *y<sub>2</sub>*), (*u<sub>2</sub>*, *v<sub>2</sub>*)}:

- *u<sub>n</sub>* = (*u<sub>2</sub>* - *u<sub>1</sub>*)/(*x<sub>2</sub>* - *x<sub>1</sub>*) * (*x<sub>n</sub>* - *x<sub>1</sub>*) + *u<sub>1</sub>*
- *v<sub>n</sub>* = (*v<sub>2</sub>* - *v<sub>1</sub>*)/(*y<sub>2</sub>* - *y<sub>1</sub>*) * (*y<sub>n</sub>* - *y<sub>1</sub>*) + *v<sub>1</sub>*

Note: we must have *x<sub>1</sub>* ≠ *x<sub>2</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>* ≠ *y<sub>2</sub>*

---

Now, if the two coordinate systems are rotated with respect to one another, you need (I believe) one more set of matching coordinates.  But it doesn't sound like you need that (unless one of your maps has north pointing in a direction other than straight up), so I'm not going to work out the math now. :)

Comment: +1. Pretty much what I was going to write. This gets rids of the ambiguity he had and of the other answers.

Comment: This is seeming to make sense but I am still a little lost. 

coodinates (538129.75, 169167.5) start at (0,0)the identical coordinates on my map are (-4.166675 , 53.816227) that start at (-4.5, 54.5)

If I had new coodinates (537353.5, 179877) or (538051.4174927.5) I'm still strugging as U1 is zero and youd get a divide by zero exception

Comment: @Vault: I've added a note about divide by zero possibilities.  Here is what the values of the variables would be for your data: x1=538129.75, y1=169167.5, x2=0, y2=0, u1=-4.166675, v1=53.816227, u2=-4.5, v2=54.5

Comment: @Vault: Given those values, for (X,Y)=(537353.5, 179877), I get:  U = (-4.5 + 4.166675)/(0 - 538129.75)*(537353.5 - 538129.75) - 4.166675 = -4.167156; V = (54.5 - 53.816227)/(0 - 169167.5)*(179877 - 169167.5) - 53.816227 = -53.859515

Answer (score 2):

To do the conversion, you need to know the coordinates of one point `O` in your two coordinates systems .

Let's suppose `O` has coordinates `x1O,y1O` in coordinate system 1, and `x2O,y2O` in coordinate system 2.

Then a point with coordinates `x1,y1` in system 1, and `x2,y2` in system 2 will satisfy:

```
(x1O - x1) = Kx * (x2O - x2)
(y1O - y1) = Ky * (y2O - y2)
```

where `Kx` and `Ky` are the scale factor. If you know the coordinates of an other point M in both systems, than you will have `Kx` and `Ky` with

```
Kx = (x1O - x1M) / (x2O - x2M)
Ky = (y1O - y1M) / (y2O - y2M)
```

Then, you just need to apply the first relationship to go from one system to another system, with

```
x1 = x1O - Kx * (x2O - x2)
y1 = y10 - Ky * (y2O - y2)
```

or

```
x2 = x2O - (x1O - x1) / Kx
y2 = y2O - (y1O - y1) / Ky
```

Do you also need the code ?